# Sitecore serialization dotnet sitecore ser validate error

Tags: sitecore-cli

[image]

I am getting this error whenever i am running command dotnet sitecore ser validate.How to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you run the serialization commands, the **Sitecore Content Serialization (SCS)** system automatically validates the content items in your file system against the content items in a Sitecore instance to make sure that they all are in the right place and that their references are in order. you can perform a manual validation of your content items using `sitecore ser validate` command.

Since you are getting validation errors you can fix it by running -

```
sitecore ser validate --fix
```

This command will correct the most common issues. In your case, it will delete the files which are extra. Also If the `--fix` command finds duplicate content items in your file system, it keeps the last updated one and deletes the oldest one. For example, if you renamed an item and added it to the repository, but the old copy (with the same ID) remains in the repository, the `--fix` argument deletes the old copy and keeps the version with the new name.